# Is there a way to access (read/write from) a specific application's sqlite database from the OS?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am modifying the android OS slightly and wish to access a specific app's sqlite database.

I know that the location is stored at `/data/data/your.applications.package/databases`, however, is there a way to load the database into the sqliteDatabase connector from outside the context of the actual app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, is there a way to load the database into the sqliteDatabase connector from outside the context of the actual app?

Yes, if the code trying to open the database has read and write permissions to the database file. In that case, just use `open()` on `SQLiteDatabase`.

So, an app running as root could do this, but an ordinary other app cannot, for obvious security reasons.

> even if I am trying to access from the kernel?

Since the kernel does not run Dalvik, you would not be able to open the database in the manner I described above.

Comment: Since I'm going from the OS, I was able to chmod the database file and load it into SQLiteDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possiblle. It is fundamental to the security model of
Android. http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/security/security.html

The other database must have a published ContentProvider implemented
on it for you to be able to access its data.
then you can try this http://androidforums.com/application-development/65082-accessing-database-another-application-using-content-provider.html

Comment: Hmm, even if I am trying to access from the kernel?

Comment: i dont really think it would be possible unless the other application has used content providers or has the same signature or has stored its database on the sdcard.